# STM32 how to recover from lock up

Tags: arm, stm32, i2c, smbus, lockup

I am trying to communicate with an SMBus battery. That has 2 sections so I am using 2 I2C modules. After the first I2C module makes a successful communication second module gets stuck. And it gets stuck in Busy. In that case I thought I need to reset that I2C module. However, I could not do it.

I tried following ways:

1) By using HAL library deiniting and then initing the module again:

```
HAL_I2C_DeInit(&hi2c1);
HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1);
```

2) Adding Swrst lines to first method:

```
//Set Swrst bit
        I2C2->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_SWRST;
//Clear Swrst bit
    I2C2->CR1 &= ~(I2C_CR1_SWRST);
    HAL_I2C_DeInit(&hi2c1);
    HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1);
```

3)

```
 __HAL_RCC_I2C1_CLK_ENABLE();
 __HAL_RCC_I2C1_FORCE_RESET();
 __HAL_RCC_I2C1_RELEASE_RESET();
```

4) Using the errata document and this line of codes:

```
void I2C_Errate_Workaround(int module){

    if(module==1){
        //Disable The I2C's
        I2C1 -> CR1 &= ~(I2C_CR1_PE);
        //Pins are general purpose output open-drain
        GPIOB->CRL |= 0b01<<24; //I2C1 SCL Open Drain
        GPIOB->CRL |= 0b01<<28; //I2C1 SDA Open Drain
        //Make SCL/SDA High
        GPIOB-> ODR |= GPIO_ODR_ODR6;
        GPIOB -> ODR |= GPIO_ODR_ODR7;
        //Check whether pins are high
        if((GPIOB->IDR & GPIO_PIN_6) == GPIO_PIN_RESET || (GPIOB ->IDR & GPIO_PIN_7) == GPIO_PIN_RESET)
        {
            for(;;){}
        }
        //SDA Low Level
        GPIOB->ODR &= ~(GPIO_ODR_ODR7);
        // Check if SDA pins are really low
        if((GPIOB->IDR & GPIO_PIN_7)== GPIO_PIN_SET){
            for(;;){}
        }
        // SCL Pin to Low
        GPIOB -> ODR &= ~(GPIO_ODR_ODR6);
        // Check whether SCL pins are cleared
        if((GPIOB->IDR & GPIO_PIN_6)== GPIO_PIN_SET){
            for(;;){}
        }
        //Configure SCL to High
        GPIOB->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_ODR6;
        //Check if SCL High
        if((GPIOB->IDR & GPIO_PIN_6)== GPIO_PIN_RESET)
        {
            for(;;){}
        }
        //Set SDA High
        GPIOB->ODR |=GPIO_ODR_ODR7;
        //Check if SDA high
        if((GPIOB->IDR & GPIO_PIN_7)== GPIO_PIN_RESET)
        {
            for(;;){}
        }
        //Set all to alternate function open drain
        GPIOB->CRL |= 0b11<<24; //I2C1 SCL Open Drain
        GPIOB->CRL |= 0b11<<28; //I2C1 SDA Open Drain
        //Set Swrst bit
        I2C1->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_SWRST;
        //Clear Swrst bit
        I2C1->CR1 &= ~(I2C_CR1_SWRST);
        //Enable I2C modules
        I2C1->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_PE;
    } else if (module ==2){
        //Disable The I2C's
        I2C2 -> CR1 &= ~( I2C_CR1_PE);
        // Pins are general purpose output open-drain
        GPIOB->CRH |= 0b01<<8;
        GPIOB->CRH |= 0b01<<10;
        //Set pins as outputs
        GPIOB -> ODR |= GPIO_ODR_ODR10;
        GPIOB -> ODR |= GPIO_ODR_ODR11;
        //Check whether pins are high
        if((GPIOB ->IDR & GPIO_PIN_11) == GPIO_PIN_RESET || (GPIOB -> IDR & GPIO_PIN_10)== GPIO_PIN_RESET)
        {
            for(;;){}
        }
        //SDA Low Level
        GPIOB ->ODR &= ~(GPIO_ODR_ODR11);
        // Check if SDA pins are really low
        if((GPIOB->IDR & GPIO_PIN_11)== GPIO_PIN_SET)
        {
            for(;;){}
        }
        // SCL Pins to Low
        GPIOB -> ODR &= ~(GPIO_ODR_ODR10);
        // Check whether SCL pins are cleared
        if((GPIOB->IDR & GPIO_PIN_10)== GPIO_PIN_SET)
        {
            for(;;){}
        }
        //Configure SCL to High
        GPIOB->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_ODR10;
        //Check if SCL High
        if((GPIOB-> IDR & GPIO_PIN_10)== GPIO_PIN_RESET)
        {
            for(;;){}
        }
        //Set SDA High
        GPIOB->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_ODR11;

        //Check if SDA high
        if((GPIOB->IDR & GPIO_PIN_11)== GPIO_PIN_RESET)
        {
            for(;;){}
        }
        //Set all to alternate function open drain
        GPIOB->CRH |= 0b11<<8; // I2C2 SCL Open Drain
        GPIOB->CRH |= 0b11<<10; //I2C2 SDA Open Drain
        //Set Swrst bit
        I2C2->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_SWRST;
        //Clear Swrst bit
        I2C2->CR1 &= ~(I2C_CR1_SWRST);
        //Enable I2C modules
        I2C2->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_PE;
    }
}
```

Is there a proper way to reset the I2C module in STM32? How can I recover from a lockup?

Edit: I am using STM32F103C8. Now I added MX_GPIO_Init function and I can reset the modules :

```
        HAL_I2C_DeInit(&hi2c2);
        osDelay(50);
        MX_GPIO_Init();
        HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c2);
```

But second module in the transmission always fails. If I use hi2c1 first then hi2c2 then hi2c2 fails. If I use hi2c2 first then vice versa. I tried to disable first module then try to communicate with second one but that did not work neither.

Comment: There are more than 1400 MCUs in the STM32 portfolio. Which one is yours? BTW, are you sure that the two buses are not connected to each other? Do something happen on the I2C2 lines while you are talking to I2C1?

Comment: I am using STM32F103C8. No that 2 buses are seperate, even their I2C slave addresses are the same. When I am talking to I2C1, I2C2 is high all the time (3.3V). The problem is I can shut down the I2C modules but cannor restart them again.After a shut down they are always high.

Comment: By the way I connected their (2 smbus lines of the battery) grounds to each other. So now I have a common ground. I just wanted to mention about it since you asked if 2 lines are connected or not.

Comment: When the I2C controller gives me trouble, I resort to [bit-banging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C#Example_of_bit-banging_the_I%C2%B2C_master_protocol).

Comment: Do the whole communication with bit-banging or just the reset?

Comment: Everything. If the I2C controller is not used, it won't lock up.